# Divide divisions in to left and right ones (like facebook timeline)

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make something similar to facebook timeline here but for some reason I can't get it. Why my right div's only follow after below first left one. I want them to start at the same spot, just like facebook timeline.

I have made a fiddle for you, so you can understand my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/FHR3q/

Also, what would be the best way to add some kind of separator between them, like a line.

Comment: just realized, the fb timeline does actually use this "issue" as one of its features..maybe you dont want them to not affect eachother.  just a thought.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write like this:

```
<div class="block leftt"></div>
<div class="block right"></div>
<div class="block left"></div>
<div class="block right"></div>
```

check this http://jsfiddle.net/FHR3q/6/

**UPDATED**

May be you can use **nth-child** property for this:

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/FHR3q/15/

with separator http://jsfiddle.net/FHR3q/16/

Comment: So the order is important, any way I can avoid writing `left, right, left, right...` and just make it place them correctly automatically?

Comment: yes, check out my answer, needs more style still, but you can just define your left block once and your right block once, and then have your content inside of them accordingly

Comment: yes order is important & check my update in which you no need to define left & right as well as order

Comment: nth-child works good under ff, webkit and ie9 so it is probably way to go. You have any ideas on seperator?

Comment: can you explain what you mean by 'seperator'

Comment: @sandeep A vertical line between both sides that goes through all page height. Just like FB timeline one

Answer (score 0):

define one block for left and right, then nest more divs inside of it, like this

http://jsfiddle.net/FHR3q/9/

also, you dont need to use clear

Answer (score 0):

If you change the order you display the html divs in

```
<div class="content">
<div class="timeline">
    <div class="block left">
        <h1>Hello, my name is Steve1.</h1><br />
        <h2>Hello, my name is Steve.</h2><br />
        <h3>Hello, my name is Steve.</h3><br />
        <h4>Hello, my name is Steve.</h4><br />
        <h5>Hello, my name is Steve.</h5><br />
        <h6>Hello, my name is Steve.</h6>
    </div>
            <div class="block right">
        <h1>Hello, my name is Steve3.</h1><br />
        <h2>Hello, my name is Steve.</h2><br />
        <h3>Hello, my name is Steve.</h3><br />
        <h4>Hello, my name is Steve.</h4><br />
        <h5>Hello, my name is Steve.</h5><br />
        <h6>Hello, my name is Steve.</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="block left">
        <h1>Hello, my name is Steve2.</h1><br />
        <h2>Hello, my name is Steve.</h2><br />
        <h3>Hello, my name is Steve.</h3><br />
        <h4>Hello, my name is Steve.</h4><br />
        <h5>Hello, my name is Steve.</h5><br />
        <h6>Hello, my name is Steve.</h6>
    </div>

    <div class="block right">
        <h1>Hello, my name is Steve4.</h1><br />
        <h2>Hello, my name is Steve.</h2><br />
        <h3>Hello, my name is Steve.</h3><br />
        <h4>Hello, my name is Steve.</h4><br />
        <h5>Hello, my name is Steve.</h5><br />
        <h6>Hello, my name is Steve.</h6>
    </div>
</div>
```